# Setup a WordPress E-Commerce site for paid downloadable pdf files

Tags: wordpress, web, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm trying to put together a Wordpress E-commerce site where the users can purchase downloadable PDF files. The user creates an account, adds the PDFs to the cart and then checkouts. Once the payment goes through, the PDF link is made available to the person for download.  I do need to track the downloads for every user so that they can download them again for free.

Is there a Wordpress plugin that handles all this? I've heard of WooCommerce by I'm not sure if it will work for downloadable content.  Please advise.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WooCommerce can handle digital downloads selling with user login: 
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/digitaldownloadable-product-handling/

You need to mark the products you want to sell as `downloadable` and then add the pdf to this product so your customers can buy and download the files.

Comment: Hi, do you perhaps have any insight on how I can setup a unique token which I can make available for a product purchase?